# I reset my Samsung Tab 4 and I lost my photos - Which aren't backed up

Tags: factory-reset

I really, really need to recover the photos. Please tell me how to recover them

Answer (score 0):

If the photos were stored on an SD card, there's software available (for a Win/Mac/Linux PC) that may be able to recover the images (works best if nothing else has been stored on the card since -- power down and pull the SD card ASAP while you search for recovery software).  If internal storage,  there might be ways to attempt file recovery, but they'll depend, first, on keeping the device turned off, because Android writes to internal storage on a continuing basis, and every write may overwrite image data.  Power down now, and power up only when ready to actually begin file recovery.